# Putting multiple elements in array through loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have multiple inputs in a file like this:

```html
<form action="card_generate.php">
<input type="text" name="tZero">
        <input type="text" name="tOne">
        <input type="text" name="tTwo">
        <input type="text" name="tThree">
</form>
```

in the file card_generate.php this have to go in an array i have wrote:

```php
$tabs = array($_POST["tZero"], $_POST["tOne"], $_POST["tTwo"], $_POST["tThree"]);
```

Is there a way I can put these values in an array through a loop or something instead of putting each value in an array one by one, there can be more values than four values.

Comment: Just use $_POST - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php  $tabs = $_POST

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can, using array_push: http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-push.php

You can than just loop like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    if(isset($_POST["t" . $i])) {
        array_push($array, $_POST["t" . $i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This dynamically checks up to 10 buttons, if you rename them to t0 .. t9

Answer (score 2):

Use input name array,

```
<form action="card_generate.php">
<input type="text" name="t[]">
        <input type="text" name="t[]">
        <input type="text" name="t[]">
        <input type="text" name="t[]">
</form>
```

And, you will get in post,

```
print_r($_POST['t']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `foreach` loop as shown in the example:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="tZero">
        <input type="text" name="tOne">
        <input type="text" name="tTwo">
        <input type="text" name="tThree">
<input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if ( isset($_POST) ) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo "Name: $key, value: $value";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

**RESULT**

```
Name: tZero, value: first 
Name: tOne, value: hi
Name: tTwo, value: firthfds
Name: tThree, value: fourth value
```

P.S. Don't forget `method="POST"` in your `<form>`.

Comment: OP says: `Is there a way I can put these values in an array through a loop`